# How to: flexible data mapping on import to laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, import

I'm currently trying to implement a flexible and easy to use import service for one of our applications. The application runs with Laravel in the background and currently we are using a fixed csv-import.
That means: the customer needs to provide a csv-file formatted by our guidelines to match the columns within our database.

Now this works fine but sure isn't flexible or intuitive.

Now I'm trying to come up with a better solution (for example like the csv import wizard used by MailChimp).

But currently I'm completely lost. I have no idea how I could use a library like https://github.com/ddeboer/data-import to achieve a solution with the following features:

- accept csv or xls
- let the user map it's data so it matches our database columns
- let the user combine multiple of source columns to one target column

My main challenge is to take in the data by the user and let them choose the mapping on their own. How do I split this process when using a library like `ddeboer/data-import`?

Also there should be taken into account, that the database may change in the next few month and I don't want to have to go back to my source code to implement these changes if that's possible.

If someone could point me in the right direction that would be really appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution we came up with looks like the following:

We work with multiple routes:

`1. /import GET`
`2. /import POST`
`3. /import-map GET`
`4. /import-map POST`

1) Renders a view with a file input for uploading a csv-file.

2) Uploads the file to a temporary path so we can work with it. The path is saved to the session and used by 3) to open the file. Since we have to deal with many different encodings, the upload function does some nasty decoding/encoding to get a valid utf8 file.

```
/**
 * Upload the given file to a temp path
 *
 * @param Filesystem $filesystem
 * @param $filePath
 * @return string
 */
public function upload(Filesystem $filesystem, $filePath)
{
    $path = str_random(20);
    $fullPath = public_path('temp/' . $path . '.csv');

    if ( ! mb_detect_encoding($filesystem->get($filePath), mb_detect_order(), true))
        $filesystem->put($filePath, chr(239) . chr(187) . chr(191) . utf8_encode($filesystem->get($filePath)));

    $filesystem->move($filePath, $fullPath);

    return $path;
}
```

3) Renders the import-mapping view. The file is loaded with the value from the session. If no session-data is found the user is redirected to 1).

```
<th>
    <select name="col-name[{{ $i }}]" data-eq="{{ $i }}" class="form-control">
        <option value="">Datenbankspalte auswählen</option>
        @foreach($tableColumns as $key => $value)
            <option value="{{ $key }}">{{ $value }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</th>
```

4) Takes care of importing:

```
/**
 * Import the uploaded file one row at a time
 *
 * @param $input
 * @return bool
 * @throws \Exception
 */
public function import(array $input)
{
    if ( ! array_key_exists('campaign_id', $input))
        throw new Exception();

    $columns = array_filter($input['col-name']);

    if (empty($columns))
        throw new Exception();

    $this->openFile($input['csvPath']);

    foreach ($this->readCsv(null, (array_key_exists('headers', $input) ? 1 : 0)) as $row)
    {
        $address = new $this->address;

        foreach ($columns as $key => $value)
        {
            if ($value == '')
                continue;

            $address->$value = $row[$key];
        }
        $address->save();
        $address->campaigns()
                ->attach($input['campaign_id'], ['client_id' => auth()->user()->client_id, 'user_id' => (array_key_exists('user_id', $input) ? $input['user_id'] : 0)]);
    }

    return true;
}
```

That wasn't too hard, was it :-)

Comment: Thank you for sharing! I would really love to see the form /import POST page as well:)

Comment: Which part exactly? `/import POST` has no page since it only uploads the file and redirects to the mapping part.